# self.view.frame.size.height returns 568 on iphone 4s instead of 480

Tags: objective-c, ios7

In the `viewDidLoad` method my view controller I call `self.view.frame.size.height` which returns 568. But `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` return 480. Shouldn't the frame size of a view always be less than the window size?

I'm testing on a iphone 4s. I tried setting the length of a sub view to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` and it was not enough to cover the screen. I then checked the size of `self.view.frame.size.height` and that is how I came across the 568 which doesn't make any sense to me yet.

Comment: in which method are you checking the height? how is the view controller created? what are your layout constraints?

Comment: I call these operations in ViewDidLoad of the containing controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` will return the correct height.

I.e, call `self.view.frame.size.height` in the view hierarchy-method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: To get this to work I had to call  [self.view layoutIfNeeded] from viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Just note that viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called for **each** added subview. In other words, it can be called multiple times, so consider not putting heavy stuff there. viewWillAppear might be a better place.

Comment: viewWillAppear does not have correct frame-layouts set. It cannot be used for this purpose. But you are right in not putting more than you need in didLayoutsubviews.

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad` the views don't have their final size. Typically they have the size taken from their XIB/Storyboard.

For example, if you design xibs for i5, the controller view will be 568 px high in `viewDidLoad`. However, before it appears on the screen a new layout is calculated (depending on your autolayout constraints or autoresizing mask).

A fix for your problem - never use the screen height. If you want to cover the entire controller, use its height `self.view.frame.size.height` instead.

Also don't forget to add constraints or set the autoresizing mask.